# Node.js Get the file names, sort them by an integer value and a return file name with largest value inside

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the folder to store users variables in a specific files. I want to create a ranking system depending on a current levels written in those files. So I need to loop and read through all files and assign the ranks.

Level files in a folder called like this: 192.168.0.2_level.lvl, 192.168.0.1_level.lvl and they holds an integer values.

How do I open everyone of them and assign a ranks? User with maximum level should be rank 1.

First part of the user.js code that I figured out is this:

```
this.IP = socket.remoteAddress;
this.level = fs.readFileSync(dbFolder + this.IP + "_level.lvl", "utf8");
var path = require('path');
var EXTENSION = '.lvl';
var files = fs.readdirSync(dbFolder);
var targetFiles = files.filter(function(file) {
    return path.extname(file) === EXTENSION;
});
console.log('Level files: ' + targetFiles);
```

At the end of user.js I need to set a rank:

```
this.rank = ????
```

I still miss the middle part of the code. Please recommend a complete solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that instead of multiple files you store the levels in one `levels.json` file and store the user rankings in a object like so:

```
{
  "users": {
    "192.168.0.2": 5, // or in an object, like this: { rank: 5 }
    "192.168.0.1": 8
  }
}
```

This way, you only need to fetch one file, and it will be extensible in the same way your current solution is.

When you´ve loaded the data, just do a regular `.sort()`:

```
var users = Object.entries(json.users)
.map(entry =>
  ({ip: entry[0], rank: entry[1]}) // maps to => {ip: "192.168.0.1", rank: 8}
)
.sort((a, b) => b.rank - a.rank)

// => [{ip: "192.168.0.1", rank: 8}, {ip: "192.168.0.2", rank: 5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your loading code by using promises. There are a number of ways of adding the functionality to node but the most recent releases have them built right into `fs`.

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const path = './lvl';

async function readFiles() {

  // Read the file list
  const files = await fsp.readdir(path);

  // `map` over the file list and return a promise to read each one
  const promises = files.map(file => fsp.readFile(`${path}/${file}`, 'utf8'));

  // `Promise.all` waits for the promises to be resolved
  return Promise.all(promises);
};

(async () => {

  // Get your data
  const data = await readFiles();

  // `map` over the data again and assign ranks
  // depending on the value in the file
  const ranks = data.map(lvl => {
    if (lvl > 100) return { rank: 1, lvl };
    if (lvl > 50) return { rank: 2, lvl };
    if (lvl > 20) return { rank: 3, lvl };
    return { rank: 0, lvl };
  });

  // Assuming the files have content like 67, 50, 102,
  // you'll end up with an array of objects that looks
  // something like this:
  // [
  //   { rank: 2, lvl: '67' },
  //   { rank: 3, lvl: '50' },
  //   { rank: 1, lvl: '102' }
  // ]
  console.log(ranks);

})();
```